# Page is not getting loaded with fecthed Data using dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

I am Selecting a dropdown, whose value is passed to a stored procedure as parameter. I am getting the data from database but the data is not getting loaded into same page.

Page A is loaded with data and a dropdown,now once dropdown is selected it should refresh the Page A with newly fetched data but page is rendering the old data. I Am confused.. can anyone help me out ?
i am able to fetch data of the selected dropdown value just that data is not getting loaded into the same page  PageA

PageA.cshtml

```
 @foreach (IcebergeWebApplication.Models.UserManager User_det in Model.UserManager)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">User:</td>

                            <td colspan="2">
                                <select name="lstuser" width="15px" id="lstuser" onchange="Checked()">
                                    @*<option id="option1" selected>@User_det.user</option>*@

                                    @foreach (IcebergeWebApplication.Models.UserManager1 user_det1 in Model.UserManager1)
                                    {
                                        if (User_det.user == user_det1.user)
                                        {
                                            <option selected="selected" value="@user_det1.id_login">
                                                @user_det1.user
                                            </option>
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            <option value="@user_det1.id_login">@user_det1.user</option>
                                        }

                                    }
                                </select>
                                
                                </td>
                            <td rowspan="7">
                                <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1">
                                    <tr>

                                        <td>
                                            ACNA Site(s)
                                        </td>

                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td valign="top">
                                            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1">
                                                @foreach (IcebergeWebApplication.Models.acna_site acna_Site in Model.acna_site)
                                                {
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                        //checkbox is getting values from DB
                                                            <input type="checkbox" name="chkACNASites" id="chkACNASites"/> 

                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                }
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                        
                        
                        <script>
           function Checked() 
        {
            var selected =document.getElementById('lstuser').value;
            alert(selected);
            $.getJSON(`?handler=SelectuserId&UserId=${selected}`, (data) => {});
        }
   
</script>

PageA.cshtml.cs
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet()

    {
        return page{};
    }


public void OnGetSelectuserId(int UserId)

    {
        HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("SelectedUserID",UserId);
        OnGet();

    }
```

[image: PageA.cshtml.cs]
[image: PageA.cshtml]
[image: PageA.cshtml.cs (Javascript)]

Comment: You're calling $.getJSON() to load the data but not doing anything with it. If you want to change the URL of the page, simply use `location = new_url;`

Comment: the problem is that your code seems to be a picture! Post CODE if you want help with CODE

Comment: I Just want to show the updated data (which i am able to fetch on dropdown change) on the same page itself. the content are not getting updated even when the updated data is available while debugging.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace the html in table,here is a demo:

handler:

```
public JsonResult OnGetSelectuserId(int UserId) {
            return new JsonResult(new List<bool> { true, false, true });
        }
```

html:

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1">
    <tr>

        <td>
            ACNA Site(s)
        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">
            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" id="myTable">
                @foreach (IcebergeWebApplication.Models.acna_site acna_Site in Model.acna_site)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            //checkbox is getting values from DB
                            <input type="checkbox" name="chkACNASites" id="chkACNASites" />

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

js:

```
function Checked() {
        var selected = document.getElementById('lstuser').value;
 
        $.getJSON(`?handler=SelectuserId&UserId=${selected}`, (data) => {
            var html = "";
            data.forEach(function (item, index) {
                if (item == true) {
                    html += "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='chkACNASites' id='chkACNASites' checked /></td></tr>";
                } else {
                    html += "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='chkACNASites' id='chkACNASites' /></td></tr>";
                }
                
            });
            document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML = html;
        
        });
    }
```